# Plotting and fitting variograms by looping

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I have some data as 50 dataframe files. In the second column of every dataframe I have the respective data which I want to do variogram analysis including fitting various modes and plotting them in individual plots for every files. So, I have a loop for it as below:

```
# Loading libraries 
library(foreign)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)


#set working directory 
setwd('c:/data/monthly')
Data=list.files(,pattern='dbf')

#load study area shape file 
studyarea=readShapeSpatial("c:/data/study-areat.shp")
#Setting the projection for study area
proj4string(studyarea)=CRS("+init=epsg:32639")

#Looping 
for(i in 1:length(Data)){

#reading dataframes
Data2=read.dbf(Data[i])
Filename=Data[i]
colnames(Data2)[4] <- "prec"

#setting coordinates for dbf files
coordinates(Data2)=~longitude+latitude

#Setting the projection for dbf files
proj4string(Data2)=CRS(proj4string(studyarea))

#defining varigram function

variogram= function(prec) {return(variogram(prec~ 1, Data2,plot.nu=T,pch=("+")))}

#fitting variograms
FitVGM = function(model_type) {return(autofitVariogram(prec~ 1, Data2, model = model_type), verbose=TRUE)}

#Defining Model options
model_options = c("Sph", "Exp", "Gau", "Ste")
#using lappy to list variogram fittings
listVGM = lapply(model_options, FitVGM)

#naming every fit by specific names
names(listVGM) = model_options
lapply(names(listVGM), function(x) {png(filename = sprintf('%s.png', x))
print(plot(listVGM[[x]]))
dev.off()
 })
dev.new()}
```

However I get an error like this :

```
Error in return(autofitVariogram(prec ~ 1, Data2, model = model_type),  : multi-argument returns are not permitted
```

Comment: Your parens are in the wrong place. Try: `FitVGM = function(model_type) {return(autofitVariogram(prec~ 1, Data2, model = model_type, verbose=TRUE))}`

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward that's right I fixed it, but I don't get any plot, still! It's just fitting the variograms and defines the parameters! How I can change it too get variograms and fitting plots, too?

Comment: Also I get the error:Error in vgm_list[[which.min(SSerr_list)]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element